# z-index issue on Twenty Eleven WordPress theme with jQuery ColorBox

Tags: wordpress, z-index, colorbox

On http://allmyzip.com/colorbox1/ there is a simple image gallery with the jQuery Colorbox/Lightbox plugin for Wordpress that opens an auto-running slideshow of 500 x 500 images when one of the thumbnails is clicked.

The site is using Wordpress 3.3.1 and the standard, unmodified Twenty Eleven version 1.3 theme that comes default with a new Wordpress install.  In IE 9, Firefox 10 and in Chrome 
16 all three browsers are showing the slideshow images BEHIND the Header/Navbar.

I have researched this for many hours and cannot find what to change, and/or where, to correct this problem. I created a simple child theme to try to test certain changes to the z-index value in the section of the style.css shown below, as some researched suggestions recomended, but changing the z-index value here to 2 or to 999 or to 99999 still did not get the images in the slideshow to display properly.  So, ALL of the CSS running the site is 100% standard, out-of-the-box Twenty Eleven CSS code.

The simple code in the child theme is limited to what you see below:  There have been NO changes to the standard code at this time.  What shows below is where I tried some 
previous edits and then returned the settings back to standard:

`@import url("../twentyeleven/style.css");

`#branding {`
border-top: 2px solid #bbb;
    `padding-bottom: 10px;`
position: relative;
    `z-index: 9999;`
}

Any specifics as to what needs to be edited and where??

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Is the site (http://allmyzip.com/colorbox1) the site with the issue? I don't see any issues with the display; the images are coming up fine in the lightbox, although there is no modal effect.

Comment: Yes, the site above is the site.  See this page: http://allmyzip.com/image-behind-header/ for a screenshot of the issue when the page gets scrolled up and down.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header id=branding has z-index of 9999, which is the same as the lightbox, so I would expect conflicts.

Change it to 5000 or something, I see in firebug that it fixes the problem.

Comment: The above answer by @RiverC was the correct answer to the question asked.  As soon as the value was changed from 9999 to 5000, the slideshow images began to properly display IN FRONT of the Header/Navbar, rather than BEHIND them.  Thanks very much for a quick and accurate answer to the question asked.  Very much appreciate it!!

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the so-called 'default' theme TwentyEleven -- how silly is it to have a default theme that contains a basic incompatibility like forcing the header to the top of everything! I hope someone catches that and fixes it for TwentyTwelve.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that

```
.cboxPhoto {
float: left;
margin: auto;
border: 0;
display: block;
border-image: initial;
}
```

may need to include

```
position:absolute;
z-index:20;
```